# Django : How to handle rejected permission in allauth?

Tags: django, facebook, django-allauth

I am using allauth 0.20.0 in django 1.8.2 for Facebook authentication in my app. Everything works fine if the user grants all the requested permission. However, I get a login failure message, when , for example, the user deny permission 'user_friends'. I assume, that this is the expected result from allauth.

Is there a way to make 'user_friends' permission optional? So, as long as I have user's public profile and e-mail, the user can be logged in.

Any pointers to methods and classes that I will need to tweak?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure the Social Account Providers in the framework and configure the settings that you wish to use for that provider. For example in the [Facebook Allauth Documentation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search.html?q=user_friends&check_keywords=yes&area=default) it describes the available settings for your login, e.g.

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
{'facebook':
   {'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends'],
    'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
    'METHOD': 'oauth2',
    'LOCALE_FUNC': 'path.to.callable',
    'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
    'VERSION': 'v2.3'}}
```

The main item you are looking for here is the 'SCOPE' setting. Here is specifies 'user_friends'. You can configure this to not request 'user_friends' and then I believe it should do what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your time to reply to my question, however it is not what I am looking for. The question is what can I do in order to let the user login to my app even if he rejects the 'user_friends' permission.